# Repeating the whole program and assigning a sentinel value

Tags: java, repeat, sentinel

I would really appreciate some help on this problem; I am also very new to Java, so please excuse any misuse of terms/any other probably clear signs of confusion. This is for a class I'm taking. I have looked this up extensively but have gotten no success. I have my program all designed (it took me so so long), but I have to find a way to make the WHOLE thing repeat itself, and essentially allow for the user to repeat the program without exiting an indefinite number of times. Since I have no integers, I'm not sure how to use a while loop or do while loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Final
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Class Reunions! This is a program specifically designed to help plan your future reunion party. Simply enter the following information, and we will  calculate the cost of your party!");
        {
            Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
            {

                String numberofhours;
                System.out.print("Please enter the number of hours for your party: ");
                numberofhours = user_input.next();

                String numberofguests;
                System.out.print("Please enter the number of guests that plan to attend your party: ");
                numberofguests = user_input.next();

                System.out.println("Please confirm the purchase of our house band: (yes/no): ");
                String bandpurchase = user_input.next();
                if (bandpurchase.equals("yes"))
                    bandpurchase = String.valueOf(350);
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
                if (bandpurchase.equals("no"))
                    bandpurchase = String.valueOf(0);

                int h = (Integer.valueOf(numberofhours) * 200);
                int g = (Integer.valueOf(numberofguests) * 40);
                int b = (Integer.valueOf(bandpurchase));
                int answer = h + g + b;

                String totalcost = String.valueOf(answer);
                System.out.println("Your expected total cost for the party is: $ " + totalcost);

                int p = Integer.valueOf(totalcost) / Integer.valueOf(numberofguests);

                String costperson = String.valueOf(p);
                System.out.println("The cost per person for the party will be: $ " + costperson);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried so many things, but nothing worked. I would like to have the whole program repeat without exiting, and have the sentinel value "Done" to stop it. Thank you very much!

Comment: `public class Final`... does this happen to be a final of some sort? Anyways... when you repeat a program, its called looping right? Well there you go.

Comment: This looks like a homework question?

Comment: Yes but looping exactly I've tried that too but I don't know how to write it because I want to loop the whole thing

Comment: Oh it's not a final it's my final version sorry

Answer (score 0):

You want something of this form. General idea is to enclose your code in a while loop that prompts the user for confirmation to repeat.

```
public class Final
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean runLoopAgain=true;
        while (runLoopAgain){
            //your
            //existing
            //code
            System.out.println("Again? (yes/no)");
            runLoopAgain=(user_input.nextLine().equals("yes"));
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you may want to check your formatting. The large block/indentation under your first print statement is unnecessary, for example.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, while loop will goes for ever till you push zero, so the condition will set new value to sentinel value and make the while loop break and come out of the loop

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sentinel = 0; <---------
        while (sentinel == 0) { <----------
            System.out.println("Enter your Name:(for exit just press 0)");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String name = input.next();
            if (name.equals("0")) { <----- sentinel variable will assinged new value      
                sentinel = 1;              which is one so while loop can be broken 
            } else {
                System.out.println("the name is " + name);
            }
        }
    }
```

output:

```
Enter your Name:(for exit just press 0)
Marco
the name is Marco
Enter your Name:(for exit just press 0)
0
```